# How to cascade delete paranoid models in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Company extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Company.hasOne(models.CompanyModules, {
        foreignKey: "company_uuid",
        sourceKey: 'uuid',
        hooks: true
      })
    }
  };
  Company.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    //.... more fields
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Company',
    paranoid: true,
    hooks: {
      afterDestroy: (instance) => {
        instance.getCompanyModules().then(companyModule => companyModule.destroy())
      }
    }
  });
  return Company;
};
```

And the other:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class CompanyModules extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      CompanyModules.belongsTo(models.Company, {
        foreignKey: 'company_uuid',
        targetKey: 'uuid',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      });
    }
  };
  CompanyModules.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
    },
    ///... more fields
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'CompanyModules',
    paranoid: true
  });
  return CompanyModules;
};
```

I have the following delete code:

```
await Company.destroy({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    individualHooks: true
})
res.status(200).send();
```

And the idea is that it "Deletes" (actually updating the deletedOn field) on both models. However I am getting an error on the `instance.getCompanyModules()`. It says that the function doesn't exist, but that's how I read it's supposed to be done. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly typing the alias for the children table. Sometimes Sequelize does not infer it. Use `as` property as follows:

```
Company.hasOne(models.CompanyModules, {
        as: 'CompanyModules',
        foreignKey: "company_uuid",
        sourceKey: 'uuid',
        hooks: true
      })
```

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#defining-an-alias